# How to put the character in the last possible place of varchar column?

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to update the last byte of a column in ORACLE.
Suppose we have a table: EMPLOYEE and in that there is a column: DEPT which is of TYPE VARCHAR2(30 CHAR).
In this table I want to update the column DEPT 30th character with a value(can be any char).

I tried below query:

```
UPDATE EMPLOYEE SET DEPT = (SUBSTR(DEPT,1,29)||'M') WHERE EMPID = 'XYZ123';
```

But it concatenated the 'M' just after where it finds spaces for DEPT value not exactly at the 30th place.

Consider the below example:

```
Employee Table: 
    EMPID    EMPNAME     DEPT 
    -------- ----------- --------- 
    XYZ123   John        Developer
```

When I ran the query it updated the DEPT column as `DeveloperM` while I want it as `Developer        M`. The 'M' value has to be updated at the last or 30th place not just after where the value ends.

Could anyone suggest ?

Comment: Are you using MySQL or Oracle?

Comment: Give us an example of your data, so we can reproduce the erroneous behavior.

Comment: i thnk u r using mysql..

Comment: If you change the type to char(30) then your code will work. If you cannot then you will have to pad.

Comment: Using Oracle.
Consider the below example:
     Employee Table: 
     EMPID    EMPNAME DEPT
     ----------    --------------  ---------
     XYZ123   John           Developer

When I ran the query it updated the DEPT column as 'DeveloperM' while I want it as 'Developer                    M'.
The 'M' value has to be updated at the last or 30th place not just after where the value ends.

Comment: Okay, I've removed the misleading MySQL tag.

Comment: I have posted a new answer below, where you can use the data dictionary view to get the actual size and then applied the right padding and finally concatenated the string that you want to add. That not fixed length, it will be dynamic so don't worry when you changes the size of data length in future. Check out might be helpful for you.

Comment: @S.Agrawal Why on earth do you have this requirement? By adding a character in the last possible position of a field, you’ve now used up more space than was necessary. Far better to add a new column to hold that value, surely? Also, if the only reason for your requirement is that you select the 30th character using substr, you know you can fetch the final character by doing `substr(col, -1)`, right? It doesn’t matter how long the string is in that case.

Answer (score 3):

This is expected behaviour a varchar field does not store trailing spaces https://docs.oracle.com/cd/A97630_01/appdev.920/a96624/b_char.htm. so given

```
DROP TABLE T;
CREATE TABLE T(DEPT varchar2(30));
INSERT INTO T (DEPT) VALUES ('ABC');
INSERT INTO T (DEPT) VALUES ('123456789012345678901234567890');
```

Concating m

```
UPDATE t SET DEPT = (SUBSTR(DEPT,1,29)||'M');
```

results in

```
DEPT                         
------------------------------
ABCM                           
12345678901234567890123456789M
```

You could rpad dept before concatenation

```
UPDATE T SET DEPT = rpad(SUBSTR(DEPT,1,29),29,' ')||'M' ;
```

results in

```
DEPT                         
------------------------------
ABCM                         M 
12345678901234567890123456789M
```

But there is a storage space cost. Alternatively you could change varchar2 to char.

If you want m to float you could test dept length

```
UPDATE t SET DEPT = 
  case when length(Dept) = 30 then (SUBSTR(DEPT,1,29)||'M')
  else (SUBSTR(DEPT,1,29)||' M')
  end;
```

Result

```
DEPT                         
------------------------------
ABC M                          
12345678901234567890123456789M
```

Comment: UPDATE T SET DEPT = rpad(SUBSTR(DEPT,1,29),29,' ')||'M' ; Thanks. Its working..

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to update 30th character of dept then only update records with `LENGTH(dept) = 30`

```
UPDATE employee 
SET dept = SUBSTR(dept, 1, 29) || 'M'
WHERE empid = 'XYZ123'
    AND LENGTH(dept) = 30;
```

Comment: Consider the below example: Employee Table: EMPID EMPNAME DEPT ---------- -------------- --------- XYZ123 John Developer When I ran the query it updated the DEPT column as 'DeveloperM' while I want it as 'Developer M'. The 'M' value has to be updated at the last or 30th place not just after where the value ends.
Your query searching for the column value length 30, which is not my case.

Comment: @S.Agrawal then you should go for solution from @P.Salmon by using `PAD`

Answer (score 0):

Here are the updates statement for Oracle as well as MySQL.

MySQL:

Run the below SQL to update the last byte the of a character for a column as below.

```
UPDATE EMPLOYEE SET DEPT = concat(rpad(DEPT,char_length(DEPT)-1,' '),'M') WHERE EMPID = 'XYZ123';
```

Oracle:

```
UPDATE EMPLOYEE SET DEPT = concat(rpad(DEPT,(select data_length from user_tab_columns where table_name = 'EMPLOYEE' and column_name = 'DEPT')-1,' '),'M')
WHERE EMPID = 'XYZ123';
```

Actual String = "India", The output will be:

```
Col_1
India              M
```